# Display current row of datagridview of childform in the status bar of the parent mdi form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, mdi, mdichild

Following is the requirement and for which i have coded the code.
When a user enters a new row in data gridview that current row should be displayed in the parent MDI form's status bar,i have put a label there and in that label text the current row's all the cells value should be displayed.i have the below code in child form but its not working.i have also attached the image of the mdi form along with child[image] form

```
Private Sub dgsalesitem_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgsalesitem.Leave
    Dim X As DataGridViewCell
    Dim v As String
    v = ""
    For Each X In dgsalesitem.SelectedRows

        v = v + X.Value
    Next
    MDILoad.lbltoolstripstatus.Text = v

End Sub
```

Comment: i have used selected rows as current row was giving error,it was showing blue wave lines

Comment: Do you want display the current row or all row values

Comment: @satson only the current row..i mean once its done editing.

Comment: did you check my answer

Comment: @satson i checked its not working on this CType(Me.MdiParent, Object).ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Leave

        Dim x As String = String.Empty

        For xi As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1

            x += Trim(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(xi).Value)

        Next

        CType(Me.MdiParent, Object).ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = x

    End Sub
```

Comment: what is this (Me.MdiParent, Object)..can you explain,do i have to replace that me.mdiparent as my mdi parent name is mdiload

Comment: instead of CType(Me.MdiParent, Object) i used mdiparent.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = x

Comment: @vimalvasudevan. That also crct. I'm converting me.mdiparent to object